# Save/restore desktop positioning of app windows on my desktop

Tags: windows, desktop

*This is not a pressing programming problem, but addresses a user experience annoyance.*

I work in an environment using VM virtual desktops, which has the annoying problem of forgetting the size of my (extra wide) monitor. So whenever I reconnect to an active logon session, the rightmost windows on the desktop have been re-positioned leftwards, as if to fit within a less wide monitor.

My question is, how can I capture and restore the **current window coordinates** for these apps (particularly Lync and the Windows Task Manager, but in general for any app window)?

Presumably, the window coordinates are stored somewhere in the **registry**, and if so, it would be a simple case of creating a small registry file (.reg) that I could re-load when I reconnect to the session which would restore the apps' window desktop positions.

Comment: No, Windows does not store coordinates of app windows. It is the responsibility of individual applications to save and to restore their window coordinates. So they can be stores anywhere and in any format.

Comment: That figures. What about Windows Task Manager, though? Is it considered its own app separate from Windows per se, or would it store its desktop coordinates somewhere conveniently accessible?

Comment: What is so special in taskmgr.exe? It is just one of many Windows accessory apps. Like Notepad.

Comment: I remember seeing some app several years ago that did exactly what you want - it saved and restored sizes and positions of desktop windows. I don't remember its name though. Or you can write a small program that enumerates top-level windows and saves/restores their positions. May be easier than searching for some ready app.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using VDI and it is very annoying that it resets all my window positions.  I solved it by writing my own little dotNet application.  You can [download the source code](https://gist.github.com/jdhenckel/129f24228be14df8d0de54ad61c03150) and compile it.  I used VS 2017 console application with Newtonsoft json library.